# pandas: fillna with data from another dataframe, based on the same ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df1` has missing values:

```py
df1=

    ID age 
    1  12 
    2  na
    3  23
    4  na
    5  na
    6  na
```

and I have another `df`:

```py
df2=

    ID age
    2   4
    4   5
    5   6 
    6   7
```

I want to `fillna` of `df1`, using `df2`, based on same `ID`:

```py
df1 (after fillna)=

    ID age 
    1  12 
    2  4
    3  23
    4  5
    5  6
    6  7
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set `ID` as index for both dataframes, and then use the `fillna()` method, which fill missing values, while matching the index of the two dataframes:

```
df1.set_index("ID").age.fillna(df2.set_index("ID").age).reset_index()

#  ID   age
#0  1   12
#1  2   4
#2  3   23
#3  4   5
#4  5   6
#5  6   7
```

---

Another option is, `combine_first`, which takes values from the first dataframe, if not `null`, otherwise takes values from the second dataframe with index and columns matched:

```
df1.set_index("ID").combine_first(df2.set_index("ID")).reset_index()

#  ID   age
#0  1   12.0
#1  2   4.0
#2  3   23.0
#3  4   5.0
#4  5   6.0
#5  6   7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Check where the nulls are and then impute the value at those places.

```
miss_bool = df1.age.isnull() 
df2 = df2.set_index('Id')

df1.loc[miss_bool, 'age'] = df1.loc[miss_bool, 'Id'].apply(lambda x: df2.age[x])
```