# Use Fillna Based on where condition pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two datasets:

First Dataset:

```
Customer_Key     Incentive_Amount
3434                32
5635                56
6565                NaN
3453                45
```

Second Dataset:

```
Customer_Key     Incentive_Amount
3425                87
6565                22
1474                46
9842                29
```

First Dataset has many rows where incentive_amount value is NaN. but it is present in second dataset. For example, See customer_Key = 6565, it's incentive_amount is missing in dataset_1 but present in dataset_2. So, For all NaN values of incentive_amount in dataset_1, copy the incentive_amount value from dataset_2 based on matching customer_key.

Psuedocode will be like:

```
df_1['incentive_amount'] = np.where(df_1['incentive_incentive']='NaN',
                                 (df_1['incentive_amount'].fillna(df_2['incentive_amount']) 
 if 
   df_1['customer_key'] = df_2['customer_key']),
                                         df_1['incentive_amount'])
```

Comment: I think your question is similar to this one, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773728/pandas-fillna-with-data-from-another-dataframe-based-on-the-same-id

Comment: @wwnde, Pandas Merging 101? This is not the main goal of this answer, isn't it?

Comment: @corralien, it is a possible solution. We should encourage some reading. I provided more read options. You can open the question if you need to

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Please do some reading

[combine_first](https://www.bing.com/search?q=combine_first%2C%20pandas&cvid=8146ef82115241b2b04e32bb85ca878a&aqs=edge..69i57j0l8.14984j0j1&pglt=43&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=HCTS)

[update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

[merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: It didn't worked. It is not copying incentive_amount from dataset_2 to datset_1 based on customer_key

Comment: See my edits, please read and take some tutorials